# User object in java abstract interface

Tags: java, interface, abstract

I saw the abstract content transmitted variable value is the interface. Please tell me how to run those functions

```
public interface Style {

    void display();
}

public abstract class ActionFrame {

//Pass the parameter to the function is the interface
    void addStyle(Style style) {
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Call class abstract 
            CActionFrame cActionFrame = new CActionFrame();
            //Call function addStyle with parameter is the interface : Style
            cActionFrame.addStyle(new Style() {
            //Override function display() in Style 
                @Override
                public void display() {
//I want to display text : "This is Test" but when run result is not output display
                    System.out.println("This is Test");
                }
            });
//How to call display ()
           cActionFrame.?
        }
    }
```

My question you've met a lot of statements like.

```
btnButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking how to compile and run Java classes?

Comment: You Suvitruf answered this question.If the next time I'll try to write more obvious question .Thank you very much for your attention,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to call `display` method of passed `Style` object, right? Then something like this:

```
public interface Style {

    public void display();
}

public abstract class ActionFrame {
    private Style mStyle;
    public void addStyle(Style style) {
        mStyle = style;
    }
    public Style getStyle(){
        return mStyle;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CActionFrame cActionFrame = new CActionFrame();
        cActionFrame.addStyle(new Style() {

            @Override
            public void display() {
                System.out.println("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
            }
        });


        cActionFrame.getStyle().display();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my english is not good,You've understood correctly, and answers completely accurate.Thank you very much Suvitruf